# Do rare enemies spawn anymore in Terraria 1.1.2?

Tags: terraria

So i tried to find Doctor Bones, Tim, and The Groom but, none i have only found The Groom ONCE!! I have been playing terraria for quite a long time now but have not found Doctor Bones or Tim. The reason i really want to find them is because A- They are rare. B- They have rare vanity items. B- It has become a goal for me to find them and slaughter them.

I understand that there are ways to cheat the items/enemies in but that won't fill that little amount of accomplishment you get when you actually kill them from luck of findings.

Undead miner and Pinky are also rare enemies but they are pretty common compared to the other three. I checked the wiki and other websites but no answers.

**EDIT:** I Finally found Tim but only after I completely destroyed a underground "House"(Those random houses with gold chests in them)... Then he became a pretty common enemy. Me and my friend joke about how we destroyed Tim's House so he attacked us.

Comment: AFAIK there is no way to farm them beyond using water candles and battle potions to up the enemy spawn amount.

Comment: @Fambida I tried both together and separate, is there a specific biome you need to be in? I saw in a picture once that Tim was in a little hut in a jungle biome, i tried to find him but no luck D:

Comment: The official Terraria wiki articles on these spawns should help you.  At the end of the day they are rare, so you might not see them, might have to accept that.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked the wiki on these entities but they show very little information, just that The Groom only appears during blood moons or Hard-Mode. Others just spawn randomly underground. Really un-useful.

Comment: @SovietOnion - So the solution to spawning `The Groom` is to force a blood moon and/or enable hard-mode.  The other 2 are likely just random.

Comment: They spawn RAREly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the comments you've received pretty much collectively give you the answer.

All of those enemies do spawn in 1.1.2; they're very rare, though, and require the right conditions/ biome to spawn.  Water candles and battle potions will increase their spawn rate, but at the end of the day a lot of it is luck.

The groom spawns on the surface during blood moons, and Tim spawns at random underground (stone layer).  Doctor Bones spawns in the surface or underground jungle at night, and more commonly during a blood moon.

So all you can really do is wander around, take advantage of the blood moons and of battle potions/ water candles, and hope for the best!  You'll encounter them eventually if you keep at it.